# How to debug classic asp page Visual Studio 2010 on IIS 7.5?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I have tried attaching the debugger to the IIS worker process and have a break point on the asp page. But it never hits the breakpoint.

I am able to debug the aspx pages in the same site using the above process.

Comment: Are you trying to debug locally or remotely?

Comment: check that you are not in release mode

Comment: I am debugging locally and am not on release mode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have got it working by setting

> **IIS Manager => Site => ASP => Debugging Properties => Enable Server Side Debugging**

to True.

**Update** : IIS Image is attached

[image]

Comment: Where do you see  Site => ASP => Debugging Properties?  I can't find that anywhere in my IIS 7.5 Manager.

Comment: @ProfK double click on ASP under IIS on the main page of IIS Manager

Comment: You need to have the ASP option installed. On Windows 7, you can find it under Control Panel/Programs and Features/Turn Windows features on or off, then under Internet Information Services/World Wide Web Services/Application Development Features/ASP.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you when attach to set it to attach to Script code only.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This should be a comment, not an answer. You can [leave a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) once you [earn](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146472/what-is-the-best-way-to-increase-my-reputation-and-privileges) enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).